# MySQL uses filesort and causes slow performance

Tags: mysql, join

I have tables **players**, **clans** and **clanmembers** which connects players to clans. What i want to do is request all players with clan information regardless of they have clan or not and sort them by players.rank (indexed).

> SELECT * FROM players LEFT JOIN clanmembers ON clanmembers.player =
>   players.id LEFT JOIN clans ON clanmembers.clan = clans.id ORDER BY
>   rank DESC LIMIT 0,100;

Query above works correctly but for some reason it scans the whole players table (lots of rows) and the query is very slow. If I SELECT players.* instead the performance skyrockets and only 100 rows is examined instead of all players.

What I'm doing wrong here? I don't understand why adding clan stuff to select makes the query scan whole player table when the joins stays exactly the same.

edit: [All indexes here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eosTJ.png)

edit 2: [Query results (EXPLAIN) here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfxyP.png)

Comment: Pls add the results of the explain for both queries and also list the indexes on the 2 tables and the fields they include.

Comment: Added to original post. id_rank was added because of Javi's answer but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like adding **FORCE INDEX (rank)** fixes the issue.

Old and slow:

```
SELECT * FROM players LEFT JOIN clanmembers ON clanmembers.player = players.id LEFT JOIN clans ON clanmembers.clan = clans.id ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 0,100;
```

New and fast:

```
SELECT * FROM players FORCE INDEX (rank) LEFT JOIN clanmembers ON clanmembers.player = players.id LEFT JOIN clans ON clanmembers.clan = clans.id ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are joining the `player` table with other tables (thus filtering by `player id`) before ordering, maybe you must add the `player id` to the index. Something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON players (rank, id);
```

And optionally, if you are always ordering in descending order, something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON players (rank DESC, id);
```

Comment: players.id is already primary key as is every id column in my tables. Should I add id to the rank index or create totally new index with two columns (id and rank)? Does this have any negative effects for performance?

Comment: Why is players filtered with id before ordering? Wouldn't it make more sense that you run a query that returns all wanted players, correctly sorted and then just lookup other tables for each row.

Comment: An extra index with both fields will decrease performance in modification queries, but improve the select queries. Inside this index every user is sorted by rank in descending order and also contains the id so it does not have to look into the full table.

Comment: I edited my answer because I put the fields in reverse order, sorry.

Comment: My apologies, this was the solution for me for a similar problem I had in the past, but the problem is not exactly the same. I'm glad you found that simple solution!